# Data not updated correctly

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2007

i got 2 forms... Dress_Price is for displaying the data form database ( MS Access 2007 ) another form,Edit_Dress  is to edit and update the database..

the code successfully updated the data based on the changes from the form Edit_Dress.. but there is 2 problems -

1. the `dgvCustomerDressPrice` did not refreshed after updating..
2. there is "space" being added to the record after updated..

   before update price value

   Dress_Name = "Tuxedo"   Dress_Price = "150"

   after update price value

   Dress_Name = " Tuxedo"  Dress_Price = " 250"

the "space" keeps being added up everytime i update the record... so the search function cant work properly because of the space..

code on Dress_Price :-

```
Private Sub Dress_Price_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS Final\TMS Final\db\db_TMS.accdb"
                con.Open()        

    dgvCustomerDressPrice()        
End Sub 

Private Sub dgvCustomerDressPrice() 

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_dress", con)

        da.Fill(dt)

        dgvDressPrice.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        dgvDressPrice.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        con.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub btnEditDress_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditDress.Click

        If dgvDressPrice.Rows.Count > 0 Then ' when user click a row, any query for database will based on Order_ID

            If dgvDressPrice.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then

                Dim intDressID As Integer = dgvDressPrice.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Dress_ID").Value 


                Try
                    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        con.Open()
                    End If

                    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_ID =" & intDressID, con)
                    ' the record that will be edited is based on the Customer_ID of particular row clicked

                    Dim dt As New DataTable

                    da.Fill(dt)

                    Edit_Dress.txtDressID.Text = intDressID
                    Edit_Dress.txtDressName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Dress_Name")
                    Edit_Dress.txtDressPrice.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Dress_Price")
                    ' pass the data from tbl_user into each represented field

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to edit data ! System eror : " & ex.ToString, "Eror !", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                End Try
            End If
        End If
        Edit_Dress.Show()
    End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_dress WHERE Dress_Name like '" & txtSearch.Text & "%' ", con)

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)

        dgvCustomerDressPrice().DataSource = dt

        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

code on Edit_Dress :-

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\annonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS Final\TMS Final\db\db_TMS.accdb")

        Try
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If

            Dim intDressID As Integer
            intDressID = Convert.ToInt32(txtDressID.Text)
            intDressID = Integer.Parse(txtDressID.Text)

            Dim intDressPrice As Integer
            intDressPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtDressPrice.Text)
            intDressPrice = Integer.Parse(txtDressPrice.Text)

            Dim query As String = "UPDATE tbl_dress SET Dress_Name = ' " & txtDressName.Text & " ' ,  Dress_Price = ' " & intDressPrice & " '  WHERE Dress_ID =  " & intDressID & "  "

            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Data updated !", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            Dress_Price.RefreshPriceList()

            con.Close()

            Me.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to save into database ! System eror : " & ex.Message, " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your UPDATE method it is clear why you have a space added every time. You put it in the update string.

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE tbl_dress SET Dress_Name = ' " & _
                                                          ^ here
                      txtDressName.Text & " ' ,  Dress_Price = ' " & _
                                           ^here                ^here
                      intDressPrice & " '  WHERE Dress_ID =  " & intDressID & "  "
                                       ^here
```

A part from the simple error that could be fixed removing the space, this is not the correct way to create an update command. You should use a parameterized query

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(.....)
    Try
      If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
         con.Open()
      End If

      Dim intDressID As Integer
      intDressID = Convert.ToInt32(txtDressID.Text)

      Dim intDressPrice As Integer
      intDressPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtDressPrice.Text)

      Dim query As String = "UPDATE tbl_dress SET Dress_Name = ?, Dress_Price = ? " & _
                            "WHERE Dress_ID =  ?"
      Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtDressName.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", intDressPrice)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", intDressID)
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      .....
```

Comment: Always use parameterized queries. They are easier to understand and you don't have problems with quotes and other required characters for dates or decimals. But the most important thing is the Sql Injection problem See [SqlInjection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) or here for [Parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: out of topic question.. 
how do i get my rep up other than asking question?? i need to post an image..

i saw lots of people got tons of rep.. do u get paid for that? o.O

Comment: :-) you should just try to answer the questions

Comment: ahaha... with my current knowledge and experience in programming.. i dont think im a suitable person to solved other people questions... anyway.. thanks a lot Steve.. if u still available.. i got 1 more question i want to post later.. i'll tag u on the post.. :)